# Scroll bar position - Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am having scroll bar issue with document library which has folders, if I scroll down and click some folder then the folder will get open but to see its contents I have to scroll up and see its contents.

Need to adjust the scroll bar position automatically on opening new folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from javascript, try this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26539/scroll-position-in-sharepoint-2010)

Hope it helps.